# Load multiple files into one div via JQuery .load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I'm trying to do this:

```
$("#Div").click(function(){
  $("#PageContentDiv").load("file.php");
  $("#PageContentDiv").load("another.php");
});
```

This issue is that the second load function is replacing the first ...

Comment: If you want to keep stuff in order, it would be easiest to load into separate divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$.get()` in `complete` callback of `.load()` , `.append()`

```
$("#Div").click(function() {
  var page = $("#PageContentDiv");
  page.load("file.php", function() {
    $.get("another.php", function(html) {
      page.append(html);
    });
  });     
});
```

Comment: Curiously, how would this work with 3 or more source files?

Comment: @faalbane You could use `$.when($.get(), $.get(), $.get())` to load all files, `.append()` each response to element at `.then(function(a, b, c) {page.append(a[0], b[0], c[0])})`

Comment: Does the $.when function happen within the page.load function? Could you update your response with an example?

Comment: @faalbane You substitute `.load()` for `$.get()` , jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ukqceuL7/ ; see http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: getting errors ... I have: $(document).ready(function(){
                                    $("#Div").click(function(){
                                    var request = function(val) {
                                        return $.post("/echo/html/", {html:"<div>" + val + "</div>"})
                                    }
                                    $.when(request("file1.php"), request("file2.php"), request("file3.php"))
                                    .then(function(a, b, c) {
                                        $("#PageContentDiv").append(a[0], b[0], c[0])
      }) }); });

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation for jsfiddle http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html ? `$.post()` was used to demonstrate process at jsfiddle. Try `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#Div").click(function(){ var request = function(val) { return $.get(val)} $.when(request("file1.php"), request("file2.php"), request("file3.php")) .then(function(a, b, c) { $("#PageContentDiv").append(a[0], b[0], c[0]) }) }); });`

Comment: It works! However, it's not replacing $("#Div") with the loaded content (as I'm going for) ...

Comment: I got it! I added a .remove() function for the $("#Div) element ... thanks again for your help!